# How to prevent componentWillReceiveProps to render for every setState here?

Tags: reactjs

I have the componentWillReceiveProps component, but as you can see, I use setState for three times here. How can I prevent React to render any time “setState” is called in this case?

```
 componentWillReceiveProps = (newProps) => {
    let apiDat = newProps.apiDat;

    let apiData = newProps.apiData;
    if (apiData.activities && apiData.activities.success ) {
        let therapists = apiData.activities.therapists;
        let hasMore = true;
        if (therapists.length < 10) {
            hasMore = false;
        }

        this.setState(() => ({
            therapists: this.state.therapists.concat(therapists),
            hasMore: hasMore,
            pageLoading: false
        }))
    }
    if (apiDat.targets && apiDat.targets.success) {
        let globalTargets = apiDat.targets.globals;
        let hasMore = true;
        if (globalTargets.length < 10) {
            hasMore = false;
        }

        this.setState(() => ({
            globalTargets: this.state.globalTargets.concat(globalTargets),
        }))
    }
    if (apiData.followActivities && apiData.followActivities.success) {
        let follows = apiData.followActivities.follows;
        let hasMore = true;
        if (follows.length < 10) {
            hasMore = false;
        }

        this.setState(() => ({
            follows: this.state.follows.concat(follows),
        }))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Build your new state inside each conditional and then call `setState` once at the end.

```
const newState = {};
if (foo && bar) {
  newState.baz = 1;
}

if (asdf && fdsa) {
  newState.blah = 2;
}

this.setState(newState);
```